# xlsxwriter not creating a desired Excell file

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have taken this basic code for the xlsxwriter website. According to them, this code should open a Excel file with hello written in the A1 square, but nothing seems to have been created and after having scanned my computer for the file my suspicion was confirmed.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("hello.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code does work:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'C:\hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')
workbook.close()
```

You should specify where the file to be created will go. For example `r'C:\hello.xlsx'` rather than just the name of the file. Also, you need to close the workbook, not the worksheet.

FYI: To format your code, just indent code by four spaces.

Comment: Can you "accept" the answer then by clicking the check symbol?